# Is physics in a way already inherently nonlocal?

Tags: metaphysics

Physical laws are mathematical constructs that define reality. However, given that they do define reality, we have a case where an abstract formalism defines reality in every corner of the world. Each corner of the world is thus “correlated” in the sense that they seemingly follow the same laws. Of course, there is no apriori reason for this to have occurred. It is simply what we observed. Isn’t the fact that reality obeys similar laws everywhere just a big non local correlation?

Comment: Sure, why not. Hume's "uniformity of nature" extends over space just as it does over time, we can call that "non-local". What of it? Is there a question beyond that?

Comment: I suppose the question was geared towards the idea of non locality being a new special phenomenon such as in QM. If we accept that a law in Arizona works the same way as in Antarctica, and if laws just govern behavior, what really is the surprise between things behaving similarly at a distance?

Comment: The same surprise you emphasized just the other day, uniform laws and non-local classical correlations have a common cause in the past, or are compatible with that, at least, quantum correlations can violate the common cause principle.

Comment: @Conifold There is a common cause between two objects that correlate because the cause is usually a law. But what is the “cause” for why the law exists in one place and also another? This is just presumed to exist for no reason which becomes similar to the non local correlations in QM no?

Comment: Coming from the same source like the Big Bang? That is how they explain the uniformity of [CMB radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background).

Comment: @Conifold Entangled particles come from the same source too, no? This then gets into what can and cannot classify as a cause. But something “causes” non local correlations in each case. I’ll have to read the link to see how “efficient” this cause is and the extent to which this is known.

Comment: They do, but the measurement outcomes are not fixed at the source, whereas the laws can be. This is the difference between emitting entangled vs classical anti-correlated particles.

Comment: That's a classic Thinkingman question- it doesn't require any specialist knowledge but does require crystal clear thinking! As a result, it is beyond me tonight, but I will certainly look forward to considering it in the morning.

Comment: "Physical laws are mathematical constructs that define reality" No, physical laws are models that describe reality.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there *might* indeed be an *a priori* reason for global connectivity. [Kant has this as his third analogy of experience](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Page%3ACritique_of_Pure_Reason_1855_Meiklejohn_tr.djvu/198):

> Things are coexistent, when in empirical intuition the perception of the one can follow upon the perception of the other, and *vice versa*—which cannot occur in the succession of phenomena, as we have shown in the explanation of the second principle. Thus I can perceive the moon and then the earth, or conversely, first the earth and then the moon; and for the reason that my perceptions of these objects can reciprocally follow each other, I say, they exist contemporaneously. Now coexistence is the existence of the manifold in the same time. But time itself is not an object of perception; and therefore we cannot conclude from the fact that things are placed in the same time, the other fact, that the perception of these things can follow each other reciprocally. The synthesis of the imagination in apprehension would only present to us each of these perceptions as present in the subject when the other is not present, and contrariwise; but would not show that the objects are coexistent, that is to say, that, if the one exists, the other also exists in the same time, and that this is necessarily so, in order that the perceptions may be capable of following each other reciprocally. It follows that a conception of the understanding or category of the reciprocal sequence of the determinations of phenomena (existing, as they do, apart from each other, and yet contemporaneously), is requisite to justify us in saying that the reciprocal succession of perceptions has its foundation in the object, and to enable us to represent coexistence as objective. But that relation of substances in which the one contains determinations the ground of which is in the other substance, is the relation of influence. And, when this influence is reciprocal, it is the relation of community or reciprocity. Consequently the coexistence of substances in space cannot be cognized in experience otherwise than under the precondition of their reciprocal action. This is therefore the condition of the possibility of things themselves as objects of experience.

Schönfeld and Thompson[[19](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kant-development/)] go so far as to claim that Kant might've even anticipated the string-theoretic idea of Calabi-Yau manifolds! Now, I would at least be willing to read field theory into the third analogy of experience, if not *quantum* field theory proper. But so the field-theoretic approach to locality-vs.-nonlocality might take the form of a denial-of-strength to the local/nonlocal distinction. So one *might* read implicit- or quasi-nonlocality into pre-QM field theory already? (Not necessarily, I mean to say; I just mean that this is a *possible* gloss of how fields, instead of point particles, interface with the local/nonlocal distinction.)